# ¿Cómo hacer una tabla que mantenga su header fijo y que además permita su control con un scroll vertical?

Tags: javascript, html5, css

¿Cómo puedo hacer una tabla que mantenga sus encabezados fijos? es decir, que cuando haga scroll hacia abajo no se pierda el encabezado de vista. Preferentemente solo con `HTML`, `CSS` y `JavaScript` sin usar otras librerías externas.

```
<style>
    table {
        display: block;
        border: solid 1px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 300px;
        height: 100px;
        overflow: scroll;
    }

    th,
    td {
        border: solid 1px;
    }

    thead {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #47D147;
    }

    tbody {
        position: relative;
        top: -50px;
    }
</style>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Apellido</th>
            <th>telefono</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Neyer1</td>
            <td>Canaviri</td>
            <td>123456789</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Neyer2</td>
            <td>Canaviri</td>
            <td>123456789</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Neyer3</td>
            <td>Canaviri</td>
            <td>123456789</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Neyer</td>
            <td>Canaviri</td>
            <td>123456789</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Neyer</td>
            <td>Canaviri</td>
            <td>123456789</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Neyer</td>
            <td>Canaviri</td>
            <td>123456789</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Neyer</td>
            <td>Canaviri</td>
            <td>123456789</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Neyer</td>
            <td>Canaviri</td>
            <td>123456789</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Neyer</td>
            <td>Canaviri</td>
            <td>123456789</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hola @Neyer, considero que ya tienes reputación suficiente como para saber que en el sitio deberías agregar algo de código para que podamos ayudarte. La he marcado como _demasiado amplia_. Intenta mejorarla y agregar algo de código a tu pregunta.

Comment: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_xy.html

Comment: sin usar librerías externas es demasiado complejo como para pedir el código desde cero.

Comment: @Neyer Si consideras que he ayudado ha responder tu pregunta favor de marcarla como valida.

Comment: Si no quieres utilizar librerías lo más fácil que puedes hacer es crear dos tablas diferentes. En una pones los encabezados y en otra el contenido. Así lo hacía para un proyecto de un banco hace un tiempo.

Answer (score 1):

> mi.html

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "scrollY":        "200px",
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "paging":         false
    } );
} );
```

```css
table.dataTable{width:100%;margin:0 auto;clear:both;border-collapse:separate;border-spacing:0}table.dataTable thead th,table.dataTable tfoot th{font-weight:bold}table.dataTable thead th,table.dataTable thead td{padding:10px 18px;border-bottom:1px solid #111}table.dataTable thead th:active,table.dataTable thead td:active{outline:none}table.dataTable tfoot th,table.dataTable tfoot td{padding:10px 18px 6px 18px;border-top:1px solid #111}table.dataTable thead .sorting,table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc,table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc{cursor:pointer;*cursor:hand}table.dataTable thead .sorting,table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc,table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc,table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc_disabled,table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc_disabled{background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center right}table.dataTable thead .sorting{background-image:url("../images/sort_both.png")}table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc{background-image:url("../images/sort_asc.png")}table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc{background-image:url("../images/sort_desc.png")}table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc_disabled{background-image:url("../images/sort_asc_disabled.png")}table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc_disabled{background-image:url("../images/sort_desc_disabled.png")}table.dataTable tbody tr{background-color:#ffffff}table.dataTable tbody tr.selected{background-color:#B0BED9}table.dataTable tbody th,table.dataTable tbody td{padding:8px 10px}table.dataTable.row-border tbody th,table.dataTable.row-border tbody td,table.dataTable.display tbody th,table.dataTable.display tbody td{border-top:1px solid #ddd}table.dataTable.row-border tbody tr:first-child th,table.dataTable.row-border tbody tr:first-child td,table.dataTable.display tbody tr:first-child th,table.dataTable.display tbody tr:first-child td{border-top:none}table.dataTable.cell-border tbody th,table.dataTable.cell-border tbody td{border-top:1px solid #ddd;border-right:1px solid #ddd}table.dataTable.cell-border tbody tr th:first-child,table.dataTable.cell-border tbody tr td:first-child{border-left:1px solid #ddd}table.dataTable.cell-border tbody tr:first-child th,table.dataTable.cell-border tbody tr:first-child td{border-top:none}table.dataTable.stripe tbody tr.odd,table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd{background-color:#f9f9f9}table.dataTable.stripe tbody tr.odd.selected,table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd.selected{background-color:#acbad4}table.dataTable.hover tbody tr:hover,table.dataTable.display tbody tr:hover{background-color:#f6f6f6}table.dataTable.hover tbody tr:hover.selected,table.dataTable.display tbody tr:hover.selected{background-color:#aab7d1}table.dataTable.order-column tbody tr>.sorting_1,table.dataTable.order-column tbody tr>.sorting_2,table.dataTable.order-column tbody tr>.sorting_3,table.dataTable.display tbody tr>.sorting_1,table.dataTable.display tbody tr>.sorting_2,table.dataTable.display tbody tr>.sorting_3{background-color:#fafafa}table.dataTable.order-column tbody tr.selected>.sorting_1,table.dataTable.order-column tbody tr.selected>.sorting_2,table.dataTable.order-column tbody tr.selected>.sorting_3,table.dataTable.display tbody tr.selected>.sorting_1,table.dataTable.display tbody tr.selected>.sorting_2,table.dataTable.display tbody tr.selected>.sorting_3{background-color:#acbad5}table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd>.sorting_1,table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.odd>.sorting_1{background-color:#f1f1f1}table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd>.sorting_2,table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.odd>.sorting_2{background-color:#f3f3f3}table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd>.sorting_3,table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.odd>.sorting_3{background-color:whitesmoke}table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd.selected>.sorting_1,table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.odd.selected>.sorting_1{background-color:#a6b4cd}table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd.selected>.sorting_2,table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.odd.selected>.sorting_2{background-color:#a8b5cf}table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd.selected>.sorting_3,table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.odd.selected>.sorting_3{background-color:#a9b7d1}table.dataTable.display tbody tr.even>.sorting_1,table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.even>.sorting_1{background-color:#fafafa}table.dataTable.display tbody tr.even>.sorting_2,table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.even>.sorting_2{background-color:#fcfcfc}table.dataTable.display tbody tr.even>.sorting_3,table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.even>.sorting_3{background-color:#fefefe}table.dataTable.display tbody tr.even.selected>.sorting_1,table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.even.selected>.sorting_1{background-color:#acbad5}table.dataTable.display tbody tr.even.selected>.sorting_2,table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.even.selected>.sorting_2{background-color:#aebcd6}table.dataTable.display tbody tr.even.selected>.sorting_3,table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.even.selected>.sorting_3{background-color:#afbdd8}table.dataTable.display tbody tr:hover>.sorting_1,table.dataTable.order-column.hover tbody tr:hover>.sorting_1{background-color:#eaeaea}table.dataTable.display tbody tr:hover>.sorting_2,table.dataTable.order-column.hover tbody tr:hover>.sorting_2{background-color:#ececec}table.dataTable.display tbody tr:hover>.sorting_3,table.dataTable.order-column.hover tbody tr:hover>.sorting_3{background-color:#efefef}table.dataTable.display tbody tr:hover.selected>.sorting_1,table.dataTable.order-column.hover tbody tr:hover.selected>.sorting_1{background-color:#a2aec7}table.dataTable.display tbody tr:hover.selected>.sorting_2,table.dataTable.order-column.hover tbody tr:hover.selected>.sorting_2{background-color:#a3b0c9}table.dataTable.display tbody tr:hover.selected>.sorting_3,table.dataTable.order-column.hover tbody tr:hover.selected>.sorting_3{background-color:#a5b2cb}table.dataTable.no-footer{border-bottom:1px solid #111}table.dataTable.nowrap th,table.dataTable.nowrap td{white-space:nowrap}table.dataTable.compact thead th,table.dataTable.compact thead td{padding:4px 17px 4px 4px}table.dataTable.compact tfoot th,table.dataTable.compact tfoot td{padding:4px}table.dataTable.compact tbody th,table.dataTable.compact tbody td{padding:4px}table.dataTable th.dt-left,table.dataTable td.dt-left{text-align:left}table.dataTable th.dt-center,table.dataTable td.dt-center,table.dataTable td.dataTables_empty{text-align:center}table.dataTable th.dt-right,table.dataTable td.dt-right{text-align:right}table.dataTable th.dt-justify,table.dataTable td.dt-justify{text-align:justify}table.dataTable th.dt-nowrap,table.dataTable td.dt-nowrap{white-space:nowrap}table.dataTable thead th.dt-head-left,table.dataTable thead td.dt-head-left,table.dataTable tfoot th.dt-head-left,table.dataTable tfoot td.dt-head-left{text-align:left}table.dataTable thead th.dt-head-center,table.dataTable thead td.dt-head-center,table.dataTable tfoot th.dt-head-center,table.dataTable tfoot td.dt-head-center{text-align:center}table.dataTable thead th.dt-head-right,table.dataTable thead td.dt-head-right,table.dataTable tfoot th.dt-head-right,table.dataTable tfoot td.dt-head-right{text-align:right}table.dataTable thead th.dt-head-justify,table.dataTable thead td.dt-head-justify,table.dataTable tfoot th.dt-head-justify,table.dataTable tfoot td.dt-head-justify{text-align:justify}table.dataTable thead th.dt-head-nowrap,table.dataTable thead td.dt-head-nowrap,table.dataTable tfoot th.dt-head-nowrap,table.dataTable tfoot td.dt-head-nowrap{white-space:nowrap}table.dataTable tbody th.dt-body-left,table.dataTable tbody td.dt-body-left{text-align:left}table.dataTable tbody th.dt-body-center,table.dataTable tbody td.dt-body-center{text-align:center}table.dataTable tbody th.dt-body-right,table.dataTable tbody td.dt-body-right{text-align:right}table.dataTable tbody th.dt-body-justify,table.dataTable tbody td.dt-body-justify{text-align:justify}table.dataTable tbody th.dt-body-nowrap,table.dataTable tbody td.dt-body-nowrap{white-space:nowrap}table.dataTable,table.dataTable th,table.dataTable td{-webkit-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box}.dataTables_wrapper{position:relative;clear:both;*zoom:1;zoom:1}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_length{float:left}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter{float:right;text-align:right}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter input{margin-left:0.5em}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_info{clear:both;float:left;padding-top:0.755em}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate{float:right;text-align:right;padding-top:0.25em}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button{box-sizing:border-box;display:inline-block;min-width:1.5em;padding:0.5em 1em;margin-left:2px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none !important;cursor:pointer;*cursor:hand;color:#333 !important;border:1px solid transparent;border-radius:2px}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.current,.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.current:hover{color:#333 !important;border:1px solid #979797;background-color:white;background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #fff), color-stop(100%, #dcdcdc));background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #dcdcdc 100%);background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #dcdcdc 100%);background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #dcdcdc 100%);background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #dcdcdc 100%);background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0%, #dcdcdc 100%)}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.disabled,.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.disabled:hover,.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.disabled:active{cursor:default;color:#666 !important;border:1px solid transparent;background:transparent;box-shadow:none}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button:hover{color:white !important;border:1px solid #111;background-color:#585858;background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #585858), color-stop(100%, #111));background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #585858 0%, #111 100%);background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #585858 0%, #111 100%);background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #585858 0%, #111 100%);background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #585858 0%, #111 100%);background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #585858 0%, #111 100%)}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button:active{outline:none;background-color:#2b2b2b;background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #2b2b2b), color-stop(100%, #0c0c0c));background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2b2b2b 0%, #0c0c0c 100%);background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #2b2b2b 0%, #0c0c0c 100%);background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #2b2b2b 0%, #0c0c0c 100%);background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #2b2b2b 0%, #0c0c0c 100%);background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #2b2b2b 0%, #0c0c0c 100%);box-shadow:inset 0 0 3px #111}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .ellipsis{padding:0 1em}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_processing{position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;width:100%;height:40px;margin-left:-50%;margin-top:-25px;padding-top:20px;text-align:center;font-size:1.2em;background-color:white;background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(25%, rgba(255,255,255,0.9)), color-stop(75%, rgba(255,255,255,0.9)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255,255,255,0)));background:-webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 25%, rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 75%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);background:-moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 25%, rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 75%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);background:-ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 25%, rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 75%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);background:-o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 25%, rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 75%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 25%, rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 75%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%)}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_length,.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter,.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_info,.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_processing,.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate{color:#333}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_scroll{clear:both}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_scroll div.dataTables_scrollBody{*margin-top:-1px;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_scroll div.dataTables_scrollBody th,.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_scroll div.dataTables_scrollBody td{vertical-align:middle}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_scroll div.dataTables_scrollBody th>div.dataTables_sizing,.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_scroll div.dataTables_scrollBody td>div.dataTables_sizing{height:0;overflow:hidden;margin:0 !important;padding:0 !important}.dataTables_wrapper.no-footer .dataTables_scrollBody{border-bottom:1px solid #111}.dataTables_wrapper.no-footer div.dataTables_scrollHead table,.dataTables_wrapper.no-footer div.dataTables_scrollBody table{border-bottom:none}.dataTables_wrapper:after{visibility:hidden;display:block;content:"";clear:both;height:0}@media screen and (max-width: 767px){.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_info,.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate{float:none;text-align:center}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate{margin-top:0.5em}}@media screen and (max-width: 640px){.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_length,.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter{float:none;text-align:center}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter{margin-top:0.5em}}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2012/10/13</td>
                <td>$132,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Dai Rios</td>
                <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>2012/09/26</td>
                <td>$217,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
                <td>Development Lead</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2011/09/03</td>
                <td>$345,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Yuri Berry</td>
                <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>2009/06/25</td>
                <td>$675,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Caesar Vance</td>
                <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>2011/12/12</td>
                <td>$106,450</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Doris Wilder</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>Sidney</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2010/09/20</td>
                <td>$85,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/10/09</td>
                <td>$1,200,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>42</td>
                <td>2010/12/22</td>
                <td>$92,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2010/11/14</td>
                <td>$357,650</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2011/06/07</td>
                <td>$206,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Fiona Green</td>
                <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>48</td>
                <td>2010/03/11</td>
                <td>$850,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shou Itou</td>
                <td>Regional Marketing</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>2011/08/14</td>
                <td>$163,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michelle House</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Sidney</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2011/06/02</td>
                <td>$95,400</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Suki Burks</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>53</td>
                <td>2009/10/22</td>
                <td>$114,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
                <td>Technical Author</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/05/07</td>
                <td>$145,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
                <td>Team Leader</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2008/10/26</td>
                <td>$235,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Martena Mccray</td>
                <td>Post-Sales support</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>2011/03/09</td>
                <td>$324,050</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Unity Butler</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/12/09</td>
                <td>$85,675</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>2008/12/16</td>
                <td>$164,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
                <td>Secretary</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2010/02/12</td>
                <td>$109,850</td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Michael Bruce</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>29</td>
                <td>2011/06/27</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Donna Snider</td>
                <td>Customer Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/01/25</td>
                <td>$112,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

prueba con css:

```
header{
position:fixed;
}
```

Comment: Él se refiere a un thead, no a un header.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo asignando un alto fijo a la tabla menor del contenido total (en este caso con `.header_fijo tbody`):

```
<table class="header_fijo">
...
```

y luego aplica este css:

```
.header_fijo {
  width: 750px;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.header_fijo thead {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #FDFDFD;
}
.header_fijo thead tr {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.header_fijo tbody {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Pero no queda claro si es esto lo que quieres hacer...